What should "skb->protocol" be set to?
As an sk_buff will more often than not contain headers corresponding to more than one single protocol, I wonder what value the protocol field is expected to hold.
Intuitively, I would've thought that it should pertain to either the most outer or the most inner protocol header contained in the sk_buff.
The function skb_flow_dissect_flow_keys however appears to assume that protocol pertains to skb_network_header.

The protocol field is set by the device driver to the low level (outermost) protocol on the medium.  For example, almost all ethernet drivers set it to the output of eth_type_trans, the transport protocol.
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.11.5/source/net/ethernet/eth.c#L155
